# arrayList only updates 2 elements when using forEach

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I create an arrayList and set all it's elements to 0

When all elements are set to 1, I try to turn them all back to 0 with a lambda and only the first 2 indices are changed.

```java
// create a list freeFrames, size 5, all elements set to 0:
List<Integer> freeFrame = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(5, 0));

// freeFrame= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

// code executes and eventually freeFrame =[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

// try to change all values to 0 if none are present
if(!freeFrame.contains(0))
    freeFrame.forEach((b) -> freeFrame.set(b, 0));

// freeFrame= [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I ended up using a standard loop. Why are only the first 2 indexes getting changed with the above?
This post seemed close https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040292/20419870 but I don't think I'm changing the size of the list, just changing the values. This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399619/20419870 suggests to use stream and map to safely modify the list while iterating. I had thought only removing and adding to list while iterating was unsafe, does modifying the contents cause an exception I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misuse of the `forEach` in your code:

```java
freeFrame.forEach(b -> freeFrame.set(b, 0));
```

`b` here represents the value in the list, but you are using it as if it were the index (`List.set` wants the index as the first argument).

Suppose you start with a list `l` containing `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, this is what happens running your `forEach`:

1. Iteration 1:

   - `b=1` (first element in the list, not first index!), you execute `l.set(1,0)`
   - Resulting list `[1, 0, 1, 1]`
2. Iteration 2:

   - `b=0` (second element in the list, changed at Iteration 1), you execute `l.set(0,0)`
   - Resulting list `[0, 0, 1, 1]`
3. Iteration 3:

   - `b=1` (third element in the list), you execute `l.set(1,0)`
   - Resulting list `[0, 0, 1, 1]` (nothing changes, it was already 0 from Iteration 1)
4. Iteration 4:

   - `b=1` (fourth element in the list), you execute `l.set(1,0)`
   - Resulting list `[0, 0, 1, 1]` (nothing changes, it was already 0 from Iteration 1)

---

You can easily replace all the elements in the list with a `for`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < freeFrame.size(); i++)
    freeFrame.set(i, 0);
```

or using streams, as you already did:

```java
freeFrame = freeFrame.stream().map(x -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but note that this solution will create a new List instead of modifying the existing list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! That makes perfect sense now that I see I was using b as an index instead of the element.

Answer (score 0):

freeFrame = freeFrame.stream().map(x -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

worked. I referenced https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399619/20419870 before posting but got confused by a previous reply

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!freeFrame.contains(0)) freeFrame.forEach((b) -> freeFrame.set(b, 0));
```

The logic behind this line is wrong.
"b" is the element from freeFrame, java.util.List#set first parameter should be the index second parameter is the value.

You need to pass the index not the previous value.